# Unity - OnDrag / IDragHandler not working on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I developed my game in Unity 5, I could drag my joysticks and any Ui normally on Mobile and editor. Since I updated to Unity 2019, Ui drag works only in editor and NEVER on Mobile touch, keep in mind: 
✅ EventSystem is implemented in Canvas 
✅ My code worked perfectly in Unity 5, and i never touched it 
✅ I have Physics 2D Raycaster on my Camera 
✅ Raycast Target are enabled inside my Joystick Ui image. 
 Help is appreciated, since i did not sleep a minute the last 19 hours trying to find a solution.

Comment: Check out [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1599969/idraghandler-not-working-on-ios.html), might help.

Comment: Thanks, this was one of hundred posts I saw and did not work for me.
I even deleted the whole Canvas and remade it under Unity 2019 settings, still zero progress made.

Comment: @federico-dondi Fixed finally.. the problem was this line of code somehow disabled any OnDrag on iPhone or Android:  Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; Removed it, Drag worked again perfectly.
Credits goes to: Siegewolf
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1601218/ondrag-methods-not-being-called-on-android-in-unit.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my Project, I have comment this line as shown in the above picture.